# How capitalize() method works in python/django?

Tags: python, django, string, methods

I have read that the method capitalize() is used to change the first letter of a string, from lowercase to uppercase.
I am writing a small website in Django (first time) and I noticed that in the template section if I write item.description.capitalize() I get some error but, removing the parentheses it works, why?

Isn't capitalize a method??

Comment: @MrGeek keep in mind OP is asking about using the method in the template (`{{ method }}`). This does not require `()` to call the method

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't capitalize a method?

**Yes**. But in Django templates, if you write `{{ foo }}`, and `foo` is a *callable*, Django automatically calls the callable. The same for `{{ foo.bar }}`: if `foo` is a callable, it is first called, before trying to access `.bar`, and `['bar']`. If that result is a callable, it is again called. This is specified in the [documentation on template variables [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#variables):

> If a **variable resolves to a callable**, the template system will **call it with no arguments** and use its result instead of the callable.

Django's templates are *deliberately* restricted not to allow subscripting, function calls, etc. Since usually that means you write business logic in the template.

Answer (score 3):

In the templates, you could use `{{ value|capfirst }}` like shown on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#capfirst)

Comment: `{{ value.capitalize }}` is perfectly legal, and it's faster (no filter function to execute).

Comment: I've never said the contrary :) The docs say what I'm saying, just that. My answer is still a valid one

Comment: That is fair enough

Comment: @HigorRossato Was about to say the same as Amadan - my issue was with "should", not with using "capfirst" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that you are not in Python any more. From [docs on Django Template Language Variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#variables):

> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute or method lookup
> - Numeric index lookup
>
> If the resulting value is callable, it is called with no arguments. The result of the call becomes the template value.

`str.capitalize` is a callable, and is called with no arguments, per above.

Answer (score 1):

The Django template language is not Python, and is intended to provide restricted access to object methods and suchlike. It's explained in the documentation. `item.description.capitalize` calls a method `capitalize` with no arguments. There is no possibility of passing arguments.

It's possible to use the Jinja template language instead of Django's own. Jinja does provide full access to the underlying Python. It's more powerful but less efficient, and most people don't need it (most of the time). [Edit: maybe not more efficient, can't vouch for this, see comments]

It's also possible to write custom filters to do particular things that cannot be expressed in the raw template language. E.g. `{{item.description|mycustomfilter:myonearg|...}}`

Comment: Not sure why you say Jinja is less efficient. According to the author (Armin) at least, the Jinja parser is much more efficient than the Django one. An effort was made to rewrite Django's along the same lines, but there were too many incompatibilities.

Comment: @Daniel_Roseman I read it somewhere and have never checked. If efficiency isn't the reason for the restrictions in the Django template Engine, I wonder why Jinja is not more widely used?